# Qué editor me recomiedan para darle duro a php?

Tags: php

Hola estoy buscando algun editor bueno para php para ir ordenando un pocos los códigos, en definitiva un buen IDE. alguien me podría recomendar alguno? He visto que usan mucho visual studio Code para ejecutar y trabajar, cual me recomendais?

Comment: php storm, visual studio code, netbeans

Comment: Pues realmente hay demasiados, pero para iniciar y ayudarte con las herramientas que incorporan como auto completar el código y mostrar la funcionalidad de los métodos puedes usar Visual Studio Code y Net beans.

Comment: Si estás empezando con php. No te recomendaría ningún IDE, te recomendaría un editor de texto lo más sencillo posible para que captes la lógica de programación y las estructuras bases del lenguaje. Por ejemplo yo empecé con bloc de notas y aunque parece poco "ortodoxo" lo recomiendo mucho porque te obliga a aprender ciertas palabras "obligatorías" del lenguaje, además te permite desarrollar el análisis porque te toca muchas veces correr en frio los programas y esto luego te provee de mayor agilidad mental a la hora de encontrar "bugs".

Comment: Los IDE's empezando son mala opción en mi opinión. Generan mucha "dependencia" y malas prácticas en ciertos casos a la hora de programar. Peor aún si son "drag and drop". Actualmente cualquier persona puede crear un "programa" o "aplicación" pero muy pocos saben realmente lo que hace cada componente, rutina, función y como mejorarlo, adaptarlo o modificarlo según se presente la necesidad. También son pocos los que realmente pueden depurar un programa sin sentirse perdidos en su "propio código".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mi sugerencia**

Tanto IDE como editores de código comparten características comunes como la finalización del código, sugerencias, resaltar secciones de código y plegado personalizado de secciones de código. Elegir entre un IDE o editor de código es en gran medida una cuestión de preferencia personal, el lenguaje de programación particular y los flujos de trabajo.

Aquí está mi lista de software de desarrollo web que ha establecido una reputación de fiabilidad y rendimiento. Espero que use uno o más de los siguientes en sus proyectos de 2018.

*Lista general: [de mayor a menor]*

---

IDE superior para proyectos de PHP

- PHPStorm
- Netbeans
- Aptana Studio
- Eclipse
- Visual Studio (con Xamarin)
- ZendStudio

Los mejores editores de código para proyectos PHP

- Visual Studio Code
- Sublime Text
- Atom
- Notepad ++
- Coda
- Brackets
- SlickEdit
- jEdit
- Programmer’s Notepad
- Komodo Edit
- RJ TextEd
- Rapid
- Ultraedit
- Codeanywhere

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.. te recomiendo que mires el [tour]... Estas preguntas no son aceptadas, suelen ser votadas negativas y se cierran (las preguntas que piden opiniones no son aptas para el sitio).

Comment: Perfecto, gracias por la aclaración.